# Did Archimedes or anyone else prior to Galileo think that heavier things did not fall faster?

Tags: gravity, galileo, archimedes, aristotle

I think I saw a high school science film in which Galileo is eating with nobility or something and the scientist amazes a young woman by simply dropping an orange and a grape, saying, if heavier things fell proportionately faster, the grape should only have fallen to *here* by the time the orange hits the table. But of course this does not happen and she is so pleased she asked if she can try it.

Surely Archimedes would have known this by observation, at least that heavier things did not fall proportionately faster which I believe is what Aristotle said. Not just Archimedes but any one of literally thousands if not millions of people in not just ancient Greece or Rome but India or China? Or really any country or people who had any sort of science? Like even Babylonians? Or really ancient Egyptians?

Comment: Perhaps they also tried dropping an apple and a feather?

Comment: We cannot know what did Archimedes think. But in his surviving work, such things as the speed are just not mentioned.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: That orange and grape thing: a bright 9 year old could see that Aristotle was wrong. But maybe the concept of speed, extremely important to most of the world since the steam-powered train, was not only not on Archimedes' mind but in most of the world where artificially precise speed did not exist, it was not an important concept. I guess once navigation became possible with clocks, speed was important too, so maybe not the train but the accurate clock which was post Galileo.

Comment: @releseable: I think the first application where speed arises is artillery, rather than navigation. I read all ancient Greek books on artillery which survived (there are 3 of them), and none of them even mentions the notion of speed.

Comment: [John Philoponnus c. 510 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Philoponus#Life)"*Our view may be completely corroborated by actual observation more effectively than by any sort of verbal argument. For if you let fall from the same height two weights, one many times heavier than the other you will see that the ratio of the times required for the motion does not depend on the weights, but that the difference in time is very small.*" He also developed impetus theory that anticipated inertia. Both might go back to Hipparchus, but we do not have surviving sources to check.

Comment: @Conifold that seems like an answer.